# Django pk is not working properly in anchor tag

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-urls

Recently I created a model to save IeeeXtreme rank of our college and created another model with it for connecting xtreme version with its team.

model.py is:

```
class Xtreme(models.Model):

    version=models.IntegerField(default=9,primary\_key=True)

    team\_no=models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def \_\_str\_\_(self):

        return str(self.version)

class Team(models.Model):

     version=models.ForeignKey(Xtreme,on\_delete=models.CASCADE)

     team\_name=models.CharField(max\_length=50)

     global\_rank=models.IntegerField(default=1)

     region\_rank=models.IntegerField(default=1)

     country\_rank=models.IntegerField(default=1)

     college\_rank=models.IntegerField(default=1)

     def \_\_str\_\_(self):

        return str(self.version)
```

and then I created a tamplate xtreme.html to load the specific version data into template. In main index page I loaded all versions of IeeeXtreme for our college and want to connect each version with its data, so I used PrimaryKey to load it through url .

url.py is:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path,include

from . import views

# from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [

path('',views.main,name='main'),

path('xtreme/<int:pk>/',views.xtreme,name='xtreme')

]
```

views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404

from django.utils import timezone

from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import *

def main(request):

    xtreme=Xtreme.objects.all().order\_by("-version")

    context={

       "xtreme":xtreme,

    }

    return render(request,'index.html',context)


def xtreme(request,pk):

    xtreme=Xtreme.objects.filter(version=pk).order\_by("-version")

    team=Team.objects.filter(version\_\_version=pk).order\_by("college\_rank")

    post = get\_object\_or\_404(Xtreme, pk=pk)

    context={

     "team":team,

     "xtreme":xtreme,

     "post":post,

    }

    return render(request,'xtreme.html',context)
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}

<section class="sec4" id="xtreme">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">

<h1> IEEEXtreme</h1>

</div>

{% for j in xtreme%}

<div class="col-sm-12">

<a href="{% url 'xtreme' pk=post.pk%}"><h3>IEEEXtreme {{j.version}} Rank of our college.</h3></a>

</div>

{% endfor %}

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

But when I clicked the link ,it directed me to the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/xtreme/%3Cversion%3E/ , but when I typed http://127.0.0.1:8000/xtreme/9/ manually it worked.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you change your `xtreme` view function to different name? Also `{% url 'xtreme' post.pk %}` will work.

Comment: I changed my name of  view xtreme and also the link in index.html in my local machine but your suggestion is not working.

Comment: Sure but I don't like my view function to name as model class name. Anyway can you explain what you did in this part `[pk=post.pk](https://pk=post.pk)` ?

Comment: I edited the question please have a look again.

Comment: I don't see any issue with URL. Please check again if the version of your db columns contains actual value.

Comment: Thank you guys my problem is solved.